# Placeholder not showing

Tags: html, placeholder

I have this HTML code:

```html
<form method="post">
    <input class="field_a" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name here"><br />
    <input class="field_a" name="email" type="email" placeholder="And your email is?"><br />
    <input class="field_a" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="We need to know what your message is about"><br />
    <textarea class="field_b" name="message" rows="10" cols="25" placeholder="Finally, the message.."></textarea><br />
    <input class="field_c" name="send_mail" type="submit" value="Ready to send your message?">
</form>
```

For some reason however, my placeholder isn't showing. Assistance on this would be great.

Comment: Looks like its working

Comment: What version of browser are you using?

Comment: Hmm.. not for me http://prntscr.com/6whx6z

Comment: I'm using Chrome, but I've also checked on IE and it's not showing.

Comment: @JugglingBob What version of chrome...?

Comment: Version 42.0.2311.90 m

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason as to why it wasn't working.

I had this CSS:

```
*::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}
*:-moz-placeholder {
    /* FF 4-18 */
    color: #fff;
}
*::-moz-placeholder {
    /* FF 19+ */
    color: #fff;
}
*:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* IE 10+ */
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This shows why it's important to provide all relevant code when asking your question ;)